# DJANGO CRUD No module named 'django.contrib.name'

Tags: python, django

when I've open cmd and command this `python manage.py makemigrations` Then I've got this huge problem. I can't understad what to do.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 118, in create
    cls = getattr(mod, cls_name)
AttributeError: module 'django.contrib' has no attribute 'name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 123, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.name'
```

WHat should I change from setting.py file?:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.name',
'django.contrib.email',
'django.contrib.address',
'django.contrib.phone',
```

]

Comment: I believe that instead of `django.contrib.name` you'd like to reference your app here. It'd be nice if you could share your code and project structure. Anyhow, the issue is because Django doesn't have any contrib modules called `name`, `email` and so on. Installed apps is where your app is referenced.

Comment: why this problem?? "" No module named 'django.contrib.name' """   how to fix?? I am new  Plzz Help

Comment: Please provide more code. Show us your models.py and project structure.

Comment: Why have you put "name", "email", "address" and "phone" in INSTALLED_APPS? These appear to be fields on your form. That's not at all where they go. Remove them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no module named

```
django.contrib.name
```

And that's what Django is actually telling you. INSTALLED_APPS variable is for Django modules that you're using in project and apps created by you. 
Delete those:

```
'django.contrib.name',
'django.contrib.email',
'django.contrib.address',
'django.contrib.phone',
```

run migration and it should work. Tell me what you meant to do with those name, email, address and phone variables and I will try to help you get it going.

Comment: still this problem

Comment: Try to look in other files if u don't use 'django.contrib.name'. If you want more specific answer please provide more code.